# libxml2 - validate XML document against schema. Retrieve schema url from the actual XML file

Tags: xml, validation, schema, dtd, libxml2

I need to validate a xml file against DTD schema. I found out that I need to pass the source of schema file for validation. Is that possible to make libxml2 find the declaration of schema in XML file and do the validation on its own, or do I have to retrieve the declaration manually?

Thanks in advance
Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could use put an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute in the XML file and let the XML processors find out where the XML Schema is.

The status of `xsi:schemaLocation` in libXML is unclear, see this bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157205. It seems implemented in the library itself but not enabled in the provided `xmllint` util.